# Code display issue in Delve for Go on Windows 10

Tags: debugging, go, windows-console, delve

I've installed Delve on Windows 10 and it seems to work but the display does not show line numbers and does not point out the current line.

According to the Delve "[Getting Started](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/blob/master/Documentation/cli/getting_started.md)" Guide I should see something like

```
(dlv) continue
> main.main() ./test.go:5 (hits goroutine(1):1 total:1) (PC: 0x49ecf3)
     1: package main
     2: 
     3: import "fmt"
     4: 
=>   5: func main() {
     6:     fmt.Println("delve test")
     7: }
(dlv)
```

But what I see is more like

```
(dlv) continue
> main.main() ./test.go:5 (hits goroutine(1):1 total:1) (PC: 0x49ecf3)
        package main

        import "fmt"

        func main() {
            fmt.Println("delve test")
        }
(dlv)
```

I can step through the code and display variable values etc, but the lack of a current line pointer `=>` makes it hard to use.

```
C:> dlv version
Delve Debugger
Version: 1.3.2
Build: $Id: 569ccbd514fc47c8b4c521b142556867ec5e6917 $

C:> go version
go version go1.12.5 windows/amd64

C:>ver
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.418]

C:>chcp
Active code page: 850
```

Perhaps there is a problem due to MS Windows Command-Prompt console capabilities? Is there a workaround or other solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you were using PowerShell, maybe you need to change the background color.
[image]
[image]

Hope it helps.